# Keep dataframe columns depending on row value

Tags: python, pandas

I start with a pandas dataframe `pm`. It consists of several columns and rows, where one row, lets call it `'active'` contains either the string `'True'` or the string `'False'`. For instance, it could look like this:

```
import pandas as pd
pm = pd.DataFrame(data={'peter': [17, 'True'],
                        'susan': [14, 'False'],
                        'tom': [1, 'False'],
                        'jenny': [12, 'True']},
                  index=['some_number', 'active'])
```

It looks like this:

```
Out[60]: 
            jenny peter  susan    tom
some_number    12    17     14      1
active       True  True  False  False
```

What I want is to only keep those columns, where the value of the row `'active'` contains is set to `'True'`. Also the strings should be casted into bools. For this example, I want the dataframe look like this:

```
desired = pd.DataFrame(data={'peter': [17, True],
                             'jenny': [12, True]},
                       index=['some_number', 'active'])
```

This must be very, very simple, but as i am new to pandas i am currently struggling with this. I thought of two steps:

1) Cast the whole row into bools, but when I try to do so, everything gets set to `True`

```
pm.loc['active',:] = pm.loc['active',:].astype(bool)
```

But it looks like this:

```
Out[61]: 
            jenny peter susan   tom
some_number    12    17    14     1
active       True  True  True  True
```

2) In a second step, only keep those columns, where the value in the row `'active'` is true. But it fails with the first step already.

A hint into the right direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd first replace the string values with their boolean equivalents calling [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html#pandas.DataFrame.replace), you can then use label indexing to select that row, generate a boolean series where the value equals `True` and use this to select the columns:

```
In [226]:

pm.replace('True',True, inplace=True)
pm.replace('False',False,inplace=True)
In [228]:

pm[pm.columns[pm.loc['active'] == True]]

Out[228]:
            jenny peter
some_number    12    17
active       True  True
```

Breaking the above down:

```
In [229]:

pm.loc['active'] == True
Out[229]:
jenny     True
peter     True
susan    False
tom      False
Name: active, dtype: bool
In [230]:

pm.columns[pm.loc['active'] == True]
Out[230]:
Index(['jenny', 'peter'], dtype='object')
```

**EDIT**

As @DSM has pointed out you could use the fact that because the values are now real bools then you can use this to select the columns:

```
In [234]:

pm.loc[:,pm.loc["active"]]
Out[234]:
            jenny peter
some_number    12    17
active       True  True
```

**ANOTHER UPDATE**

If you're worried about calling replace on the whole df then you can call `replace` just on that row:

```
pm.loc['active'].replace('True',True, inplace=True)
pm.loc['active'].replace('False',False,inplace=True)
```

Comment: Not sure I'd index into `pm.columns`; wouldn't `pm.loc[:,pm.loc["active"]]` give the same results (after we make active into bools)?

Comment: @DSM yes I guess that would be cleaner I was approaching this in a more literal sense with respect to what the OP wanted but yes once the values are bools then that would work, I'll update my answer

Comment: This does achieve my goal. Didn't think of replace. In my case it seems safe to replace on the whole dataframe, is there a way to only replace the strings of one specific row, i.e. the row called ``'active'``?

Comment: @Nras you can call `replace` just on that row by using `loc` to perform row label selection